# Single page navigation not working properly

Tags: javascript, winjs

I'm issuing a problem with single page navigation in WinJS app for windows 8.1 : 
I have a lot of pages on my app, and many of them have elements with same IDs (links to the same page called "myPage", for example). But something strange happens:
On "page1", i have links to "page2" and "page3". on "page2" i have a link to "page1" and "page3".
If i navigate from "page1" to "page2" and then back to "page1" and finally to "page3", that last link does not run.
on the load function of "page1", i set all the eventHandlers for navigation like this example

```
document.getElementById("page3").onclick = function () {
    WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/page3/page3.html");
};
```

same code is present on load function of link to "page3" in "page2"
the elements got the same id.
if i navigate directly to "page3" without going through "page2" it works properly.

There is a way to avoid this issue without changing all the elements id?

Comment: It seems like DOM elements being not disposed immediately; if I navigate to an other empty page and then to "page2", all works properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait, until all resources are loaded.

```
    WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function () {
        document.getElementById("page3").onclick = function () {
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/page3/page3.html");
        };
    });
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/apps/hh440975.aspx

Comment: i solved this callin an `my_init()` function after a 1ms delay with `setTimeout`, but thank you, your solution works too

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `WinJS.UI.processAll()` function in your `onClick()` function. Basically, wrapping your logic this function will fix the problem.